# Join no Eloquent - Join no Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.3

Estou aprendendo `Laravel` agora, e por curiosidade me deparei com o seguinte problema, realizar um join entre duas tabelas, no meu caso, "`categorias`" e "`subcategorias`", no qual quando irei listar as `subcategorias`.

Ele buscar o nome da categoria ao qual ela esta relacionada e exibi-lo, sei que seria mais fácil usando o `DB::`, mas por questão de curiosidade e aprendizado gostaria de saber como fazer isso no `Eloquent`?

***Tabela Categorias***

```
id_categoria - PK
nome_categoria
```

***Tabela Subcategorias***

```
id_subcategoria - PK
nome_subcategoria
idcategoria_subcategoria - armazena o id da categoria
```

Comment: Deu certo Carlos?

Comment: Dá uma lida nisso também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer e também https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help para criar e aceitar respostas!

Comment: Opa Virgilio, ainda não, ele não exibe os dados, agora fiquei com uma duvida, oq eu coloco no $p?? Pq vão ser várias categorias, se eu especificar uma, ele não exibiria somente aquela?

Comment: consegui eibir, mas ele só exibe da categoria especificada.

Comment: O que você queria, porque, então a sua pergunta está mau formulada? Qualquer coisa coloque na sua pergunta a idéia dom `DB::` que você disse que seria mais fácil! como seria? ai eu posso traduzir para Eloquent!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro precisa configurar seus models [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent):

***Categorias***

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Categorias extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'categorias';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_categoria';
    protected $fillable = ['nome_categoria'];
    public  $timestamps = false;

    public function subcategorias()
    {        
        return $this->hasMany(SubCategorias::class,
                              'idcategoria_subcategoria', 'id_categoria');
    }    
}
```

---

***SubCategorias***

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SubCategorias extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'subcategorias';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_subcategoria';
    protected $fillable = ['nome_subcategoria', 'idcategoria_subcategoria'];
    public  $timestamps = false;

    public function categoria()
    {        
        return $this->belongsTo(Categorias::class,
                               'idcategoria_subcategoria', 'id_categoria');
    }    
}
```

Verifique se os nomes das tabelas são esses mesmos (categorias e subcategorias) que foram colocados nas configurações `protected $table` se não altere para o nome corresponde.

Para fazer as pesquisa utilize [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) da seguinte forma:

```
$p = 'texto de busca';
$subCategorias = SubCategorias::whereHas('categoria', function ($query) use ($p) {
    $query->where('nome_categoria', 'like', $p);
})->get();
```

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)
- [Eloquent: Querying Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

Comment: consegui eibir, mas ele só exibe da categoria especificada no $p